# How can I disable IIS redirection from subdomain to www?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I'm creating a subdomain on IIS called:

```
buy.mydomain.com
```

I've set this up AFAICT as a plain vanilla site in IIS, but whenever I hit this in the browser, I get a 302 redirect to:

```
www.buy.mydomain.com
```

I can't find any place in the configuration or code that would be causing this redirection. Can anyone point me to what would be making IIS behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS does not have that configuration by default, if you have access to the server I would enable failed request tracing to see why that is the case (which module is returning the status 302).
For example I would add a rule in your web.config (assuming you have enabled Failed Request Tracing) like:

```
<tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests>
    <add path="*">
      <traceAreas>
        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite" verbosity="Verbose" />
      </traceAreas>
      <failureDefinitions statusCodes="301-308" />
    </add>
  </traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
```

what could be happening also is sometimes browsers will try to add the "www" if they are not being able to reach out the server, so you might want to use Fiddler as well to see if you indeed are getting that 301/302/307 redirect from the server or it is the browser or an extension just trying to be smart.

One option could be either the URL Rewrite module or the URL Redirect module, so double checking their configuration in IIS Manager would be a good idea.